# Use of partial integration - uncertainty principle

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

$let f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \text{ and } a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$ \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} (x-a)^2 |f(x)|^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R} }(\xi-b)^{2} |\hat{f}(\xi) |^2 d\xi\right)^{1/2} \geq \frac{1}{2} ||f||_2^2$$

I dont understand the first steps of the proof:

Without loss of generality let $a,b=0 \text{ and } ||f||_2^2 = 1$.
Then $$1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R} }x \frac{d}{dx} |f(x)|^2 dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R} }x f'(x)\overline{f(x)} + x\overline{f'(x)}f(x)dx $$

They say, that partial integration was used. I assume it was used in the second equality where the minus appears. But I run into trouble there:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x'|f(x)|^2 dx= x|f(x)|^2 - \int_{\mathbb{R}}x \frac{d}{dx} |f(x)|^2dx$$ So, where does the $x|f(x)|$ hide in the proof?

Comment: It should be an $[x|f(x)|^2]^\infty_{-\infty}$ and usually the assumption in physics is that $f$ vanishes at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: But how can we with $f'(x)$ if $f$ is not differentiable?